# Cannot compare Firebase latitude/longitude values in didUpdateLocations

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, cllocationmanager

I am dealing with a simple issue in regards to fetching data from Firebase and using that data elsewhere in my code. Below, I have a function that retrieves the latitude and longitude of a location and stores them in two variables `locationLat` and `locationLong` defined and initially set to 0.0. I call this function in `viewDidLoad`.

The two variables which hold the latitude and longitude are then accessed in `didUpdateLocations` to compare the user's location with the latitude and longitude of the values that were fetched from Firebase.

My Problem: The if condition in `didUpdateLocations` will not work all the time and when it doesn't, the latitude and longitude prints 0.0 or nil and it does not run the if statement.

I understand that observeSingleEvent is asynchronous in nature but I'm not sure on how to use Firebase data properly in my code when I retrieve it especially in the `didUpdateLocations` delegate function. Any advice would be great.

Below are the two functions associated with this problem. The first one is my function that retrieves the latitude and longitude from Firebase. The second function is my `didUpdateLocations` function where my bug occurs.

```swift
func getLocationCoordinates() {
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("map").child(self.titleString)
        ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
                let nameSnapshots = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "title")
                let val = nameSnapshots.value as! String
                if self.locationName.text == val {
                    let latitude = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "latitude")
                    let longitude = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "longitude")
                    let latValue = latitude.value as! CLLocationDegrees
                    let lonValue = longitude.value as! CLLocationDegrees
                    self.locationLat = latValue
                    self.locationLong = lonValue
                }
            }
        }
```

and here is the `didUpdateLocations` function

```swift
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        let userLocation :CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation
        let locationAddress: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: locationLat, longitude: locationLong)
        print("loc latitude = \(locationAddress.coordinate.latitude)")
        print("loc longitude = \(locationAddress.coordinate.longitude)")
        let distanceFrom : CLLocationDistance = userLocation.distance(from: locationAddress)
        if 300 >= distanceFrom {
            checkInOutlet.isEnabled = true
            print("we are here")
        } else {
            checkInOutlet.isEnabled = false
            print("not here yet")
        }
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted could tell me what was wrong with my question since this isn't something that was asked before or often and my question was very clearly on what was wrong.

Comment: Both of calls are async, either save `userLocation` as ivar and have same if check within `ref.observeSingleEvent` call back or find other solution to solve this problem.  Just remember that both calls are async

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your `getLocationCoordinates` and `didUpdateLocations` are `async` calls you need wait until `getLocationCoordinates` give a result from firebase server and use a return value into `didUpdateLocations` method.

for that you can use `completion` closure. Check below example code:

```
func getLocationCoordinates(completion: @escaping (_ lat: CLLocationDegrees, _ lon: CLLocationDegrees)->()) {

    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("map").child(self.titleString)
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        let nameSnapshots = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "title")
        let val = nameSnapshots.value as! String
        if self.locationName.text == val {
            let latitude = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "latitude")
            let longitude = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "longitude")
            let latValue = latitude.value as! CLLocationDegrees
            let lonValue = longitude.value as! CLLocationDegrees
            self.locationLat = latValue
            self.locationLong = lonValue

            completion(latValue, lonValue) //this will return your data
        }
    }
}
```

I have modified your `getLocationCoordinates` with `completion` callback and `completion` will call when it gets data from firebase server and return `lat` and `lon` values from that call.

Now you need to use that in your `didUpdateLocations` method like shown below:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    let userLocation :CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation

    //call your method like this
    getLocationCoordinates { (lat, lon) -> () in

        //use lat and lon which returned by above method
        let locationAddress: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
        print("loc latitude = \(locationAddress.coordinate.latitude)")
        print("loc longitude = \(locationAddress.coordinate.longitude)")
        let distanceFrom : CLLocationDistance = userLocation.distance(from: locationAddress)
        if 300 >= distanceFrom {
            self.checkInOutlet.isEnabled = true
            print("we are here")
        } else {
            self.checkInOutlet.isEnabled = false
            print("not here yet")
        }
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```